# How to print without the ''[]

Tags: python, printing

So i just created a simple team generator

```
import time
from random import choice

players=input("Name of the player:").split(',')

team1=[]
team2=[]

while len(players)>0:
    player1 = choice(players)
    team1.append(player1)
    players.remove(player1)

    if players == []:
        break

    player2 = choice(players)
    team2.append(player2)
    players.remove(player2) 

print("team1\n", team1)
print("team2\n", team2)

time.sleep(20)
```

But it comes out like this:

```
Team1
['PlayerA', 'PlayerB']
Team2
['PlayerC', 'PlayerD']
```

How can i make it to appear without []'' and to make the players names appear vertical?
Something like this:

```
Team1
PlayerA
PlayerB
Team2
PlayerC
PlayerD
```

Comment: Even though your question is tagged as python it would be useful to repeat that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the print statement to:

```py
print("Team1", *team1, sep='\n')
print("Team2", *team2, sep='\n')
```

The asterisk unpacks the list to its individual items, instead of printing the list as a whole. By specifying the items should be separated by a new line instead of the default space all items end up on a new line:

```
Name of the player: a,b,c,d
Team1
b
a
Team2
d
c
```